# Javascript bind extra params

Tags: javascript, apply, call, bind

I need to pass a run time argument to function. I am using `bind` to bind the function to argument. However when the function is called runtime argument is not available. the setup is similar to below:

```js
const testFunction = (event, message) => {
  console.log(message); //message is undefined
}
const bindTheMessage = () => {
  testFunction.bind(document.getElementById('testButton'), 'hello');
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <button id='bindButton' onclick='bindTheMessage()'>bind a message</button>
  <button id='testButton' onclick='testFunction()'>click to get message</button>
</body>
<html>
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: `bind` doesn't alter a function object, it returns a new function.

Comment: Also the order of your arguments seems wrong - do you want to bind `'hello'` as `message`?

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems.

## It doesn't mutate

`bind` **returns** a function which calls the original function with certain arguments.

It doesn't mutate the original function.

You'd need something like:

```
testFunction = testFunction.bind(...)
```

for that (and then clicking `bindTheMessage` multiple times would keep nesting it)

## You missed an argument

Look at the [documentation for bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind):

> ```
> bind(thisArg, arg1, ... , argN)
> ```

The first argument is the `this` value. Subsequent arguments are the parameter values.

You have bound the button element to `this` and `'hello'` to `event` but nothing to `message`.

Answer (score 0):

The shortest way to get from where you are to your desired result is outlined below. You need to set aside the function returned by `testFunction.bind`, and and use *that* function as your event handler, not the original `testFunction` which is not altered by calling `bind` on it.

You also need to pass the `event` into your function if you want the `event` argument to be set, and that needs to be the last argument to the function in order for you to bind the first two.

```js
let boundTestFunction

const testFunction = (message, event) => {
  console.log(message);
  console.log(event);
}
const bindTheMessage = () => {
  boundTestFunction = testFunction.bind(document.getElementById('testButton'), 'hello');
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <button id='bindButton' onclick='bindTheMessage()'>bind a message</button>
  <button id='testButton' onclick='boundTestFunction(event)'>click to get message</button>
</body>
<html>
```

All this said, I would not use inline event handlers here. I would do something like the following:

```js
const testFunction = (message, event) => {
  console.log(message);
  console.log(event);
}

document.getElementById("bindButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementById("testButton").addEventListener("click", testFunction.bind(document.getElementById('testButton'), 'hello'));
})
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <button id='bindButton'>bind a message</button>
  <button id='testButton'>click to get message</button>
</body>
<html>
```